# Deploying workflows from Visual Studio problems

Tags: workflow, deployment, visual-studio-2012

I recently ran into a problem while trying to deploy WSP containing workflow 2013 SPIs. Visual Studio 2012 couldn't delete workflows and workflow associations during deployment process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of trial and error I noticed that Fiddler was running on the server which is quite common when debugging workflows.

When I closed Fiddler I was able to deploy WSP successfully. I was able to recreate this issue multiple times.

For more details: http://slavensemper.blogspot.com/2014/08/error-occurred-in-deployment-step.html

So, close Fiddler when deploying Workflows

**EDIT:**

It isn't even necessary to close Fiddler, it is enough to stop capturing traffic. This can be achieved by clicking the label "Capturing" in the lower left corner of the status bar:
[image]